# a SOAP reader and writer in JAVA?

Tags: java, soap-client

I want to make a web service client and need a free reader/writer which can read/write soap messages and I easily just set/get message parameters.

I have my own network infrastructures and I want to work with them, and I just need something that can read/write from/to a byte array, or ByteBuffer, or somthing...

Is there any good hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SAAJ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html) should do the job, and it comes standard with Java as of Java 6.

Reading from input stream:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in = ...;
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), in);
System.out.println(message.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagNameNS("http://tempuri.org", "MyOperation"));
```

Writing:

```
SOAPMessage message = ...;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
message.writeTo(out);
System.out.println(out);
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the protocol when creating the MessageFactory instance: MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL)?